# Git: How to pull changes from remote that are unstaged or not committed?

Tags: git, github

Here's the situation. I have a cloned repo from GitHub on my host dev machine. Then on a virtual machine, I've cloned the sources from the host machine. Then I make changes to the source on the host machine, yet I want to run the source on VM. I do this because I crash the VM "a lot" and want to make sure I don't lose my source in case something goes corrupt as well as look at fixes while the VM boots up (as fs checks take a while sometimes).

So the issue is, how can I pull the changes I make to the source on the host without having to do commits for each and every change? Staging the changes doesn't seem to be enough. Is there another way so that I don't have to commit changes where all I'm doing is debugging?

Comment: "without having to do commits for each and every change" - what do you mean by "change", exactly? Are you asking if you need to do a commit for each single changed line, file, or folder? (In which case the answer is "no", a commit's changes can be arbitrarily large).

Comment: Why did you mention staging changes? That's unrelated to moving project files between computers - I suspect that you haven't yet *groked* how `git` works...

Comment: @Dai, by changes, I mean, just changing a single line of code. I figured it might not be possible.

Comment: Git supports committing individual lines of code - but you need to use a git GUI that supports line-by-line commits and hunk-based commits. Visual Studio (surprisingly) still does not support line-based commits. Other Git GUIs (like GitKraken) do - and once you start using line and hunk-based commits you won't look back.

Comment: After you've made unstaged changes, you can use `git diff > foo.diff` to generate a patch. Get the patch and apply it on VM repository with `git apply --reject foo.diff`. But `git commit` can make it much easier.

Comment: @ElpieKay Good idea with suggesting `git diff` (I didn't think of that!) but the problem there is applying diffs without commits makes it difficult to undo changes or do a `rebase` after removing a commit. I'll admit that I still don't fully understand what the OP's objective is, though.

Comment: So far, I think I'll just continue to use "scp *.c me@dest:~/repo", seems to be easiest, though I have to be aware of what I'm doing when I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> without having to do commits for each and every change?

You can't. That's what commits are for. (Oversimplification warning) **A commit is the atomic unit of `git`**. You can *squash* commits, of course, but you'll need to do that before you `push` otherwise you'll break your refs on the remote machine.

If you have casual changes that you want to move-over but don't want to introduce to your "real" codebase then put the changes in a separate branch.

That said, `git` is a tool for distributed source-control. It is *not* a tool for synchronizing ad-hoc code-changes between two machines for a work-in-progress (you *can* use it for this purpose, but it's not ideal). Ideally you'd use something like [magic-wormhole](https://github.com/warner/magic-wormhole) (or your hypervisor's native file transfer utility) and/or `rsync` to move code-state between machines.